# Storyboard.hideOverlay: accessing parent functions issue

Tags: lua, corona-storyboard

So Ive been wondering if this is possible to do, as it is important for my game.

Basically I have a menu.lua file (game plays only from this one file) but before the game loads up, I initiate this code which loads up a new lua file (tutorial.lua)

```
storyboard.showOverlay("tutorial", {effect="fromRight", isModal=true, time=50})
```

Now when I use this code to get back to menu.lua, the game does nothing.

```
storyboard.hideOverlay({"fromTop"})
```

The reason why is because my game begins from calling beginGame() from menu.lua. So I would like to ask if I can somehow call beginGame() from menu.lua once storyboard.hideOverlay code complete from within tutorial.lua

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Corona no longer supports Storyboard implementation., So start using Corona Composer library. [Corona Docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html)

In composer refer this to start the game when overlay hides. [hideOverlay](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/hideOverlay.html)